# Get top 5 post count sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to get the top 5 users in my database according to their post count

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pins ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 5")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
    Print "<table><tr><td>";
    Print "".$info['user_id']."";
    Print "</td></tr></table>";
} 
?>
```

This is a code I have adapted which works for individual users with a `WHERE user_id='999'` clause. But how do I change it to get the top 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM pins
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the `ORDER BY COUNT(*)` which I was unaware of.